# How to get an equation from a "ball is thrown" word problem?

Tags: functions, word-problem

"A ball is thrown upward from the roof of a building $60$m tall. The ball reaches a height of $80$m above the ground after $2$ s and hits the ground $6$ s after being thrown." How do I determine the equation without using physics(constants related to physics) ideas?

It should be in the form $y= ax^2+ bx + c$, right? I got $60$ for the $y$-intercept so $y= ax^2+ bx + 60$. The ball had the height of $80$ meters at $2$ seconds. It dropped to the ground in $4$ seconds. So $\frac{80}{4}=b\implies b=20$?  I found $a$ and got $-5x^2 + 20x + 60$ but do my steps show I understand the problem?

Comment: How can one answer a physics question without using physics?  And what is the question?

Comment: @Dr.MV:  when there is too much information supplied, so there is enough to measure $g$.  We still need the assumption that $g$ is constant.

Comment: Please define your variables and show more steps.  You appear to start with $x$ for time in seconds, but at the end $t$ appears.  How did you get to $80/4=b?$  There is also a typo of $6$ for $60$ in the $y$ intercept.  I suspect you understand the problem and $a$ is not the canonical $9.81$, but you haven't shown enough steps to show you understand it.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ross, what is the question that the OP is trying to answer?   And how does one answer a physics question without physics?  That is, what defined the trajectory (path) of the object.

Comment: @Dr.MV:  once you accept the trajectory is quadratic, which to my mind is certainly physics, you can evaluate $a$ and $b$ from the data given. You don't have to accept that $a=-9.81$.  I find a different value for $a$

Comment: The question is, determine an equation for the function. x is time and y is height. I "guessed" that because the ball went to the ground 4 seconds after its maximum height at (2,80), 80 meters/4 seconds = b = 20 Actually, I suspect this is a mistake. Should I plug in 2 different points and then find the POI, or rather, find a or b?

Comment: You were not given that the (2,80) point is the maximum height, so  I would say you did not show you understand the question.  Yes, you should plug in the two different points and solve the two simultaneous equations to find $a,b$  In fact, you should know that $(2,80)$ is not the maximum height because the parabola is symmetric around the vertex.  As you started at $60$ and ended at $0$, the vertex must be to the left of $2$

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying the vertex is at (0,60)?

Answer (score 1):

Physics says two things.  First, that the acceleration from gravity is constant, and second, that the acceleration is $-9.81 m/s^2$.  You have accepted the first, which results in $y=ax^2+bx+c$ (assuming $x$ is time) but rejected the second.  That is fine, you have enough data to evaluate all the constants, as you have three points on the parabola and need three constants, $a,b,c$. As you say, $c=60$ is immediate.

Comment: We know the equation is y=ax^2+ bx +60. I'd put in the point (2,80) to get 80=a(2)^2 + b(2) +60. Put in the point (6,0) to get 0=a(6)^2 + b(6) +60. Now I have 2 equations with 2 unknowns. I used all 3 points to find all 3 constants by solving for a, and then b. Does this work?

Comment: Yes, that works fine.  It turns out $b=20$, but your logic in the question does not justify that.

Comment: I don't understand why my method works, actually. Did I find the point of intersection? Could I have used any other 2 points?

Comment: You were lucky.  It turns out $(2,80)$ is the peak, but that is not given. You can write it as $y=-5(x-2)^2+80$.  If the ground were at the launch altitude the equation would be $y=-5(x-2)^2$ and it would have hit the ground at $4$ seconds.  You would have found $b=20/2=10$ because the peak was $20$ and it hit the ground $2$ seconds later.

Comment: No, I mean, the second method. The one where I put in (2,80) and (0,6). I don't understand why that works. Would you tell me?

Comment: You have three points on the parabola, if you add in $(0,60)$.  That gives you three equations in the three unknowns $a,b,c$  You are just solving the three simultaneous equations to find them.  As you noted in the question, the fact that you have a value at $x=0$ makes finding $c$ immediate.